# Printf not working when function conditions are met

Tags: c, function

I've written a function getIntLimited that asks the user to input a valid integer between 10 and 20 and getIntLimited calls a function getInt to confirm if the input is a valid integer. Everything works as intended expect for if the user actually inputs a valid integer that is between 10 and 20. It will simple proceed to a blank newline to scan another input instead of outputting the printf statement `("You entered: %d \n", iVal);` I'm not sure why it doesn't output the printf statement when the conditions are met. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//tools
void flushKeyboard(void);
void pause(void);
int getInt(void);
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);
double getDoubleLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);

//app interface

int main(void){
    flushKeyboard();
    pause();

    int answer;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    answer = getInt();
    printf("You entered: %d \n", answer);

    int iVal;
    printf("Enter an integer between 10 and 20: ");
    int lowerLimit = 10;
    int upperLimit = 20;

    iVal = getIntLimited(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    printf("You entered: %d \n", iVal);

    return 0;
    }


//code your functions here:
void flushKeyboard(void)
{
    int read;

    while (( read = getchar()) != '\n' && read != EOF) {
    continue;
}
    return;
}

void pause(void)
{
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
    flushKeyboard();
    return;
}

int getInt(void)
{
    int Value;
    char NL = 'x';

    while (scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL) != 2 || NL != '\n') {
        flushKeyboard();
        printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");
    }

    return Value;
}


int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
    int limit;
do {
    limit = getInt();

    if(lowerLimit > limit || upperLimit < limit) {
        printf("Invalid value, %d < %d < %d: ", lowerLimit, limit,     upperLimit);
    }
}while(lowerLimit <= limit || upperLimit >= limit);
return limit;

}
```

Comment: Note: `(lowerLimit > limit || upperLimit < limit)` is not the opposite of `(lowerLimit <= limit || upperLimit >= limit)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `do`/`while` condition describes the inverse of what you actually want to happen: you want the loop to end when `limit` is between `lowerLimit` and `upperLimit`.

While you are at it, consider renaming the variable `limit` to something more descriptive - say, `value`, or `result`, because the number the user entered is *not* used as a limit.

The condition should be

```
do {
    ...
} while(result < lowerLimit || result > upperLimit);
```